# SASS - When Class is Activated - Change Another

Tags: css, sass

In my SASS file I have some styling for a slick carousel and a loading spinner.

When the class `slick-initialized` appears is it possible to set `display:none` on the spinner.

For example - from:

```
slick.slick-initialized {
  display: block;
}
```

To something like:

```
slick.slick-initialized {
      display: block;

      &.spinner { display none };
}
```

where I have:

```
<div class="row">

      <div class="spinner"></div>

      <slick init-onload=true data="qNew" dots=true arrows=false>
        <div class=“tile" ng-repeat="question in questionsNew">
          <span ng-bind-html="question.question"></span>
        </div>
      </slick>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to show us your HTML structure. Is `.spinner` within `slick`?

Comment: No - its a seperate bit of code I'm using - basically like `<div class="spinner></div>`

Comment: According to description and scss code it will produce the result you wanted if `.spinner` is inside `.slick`

Comment: Can you show us your HTML as well

Comment: @AkashKOdesia updated question

Comment: @userMod2 Where will `slick.slick-initialized` class appear in given HTML

Comment: Slick is a JS library so essentially writes code to support - if that makes sense?

Comment: I may just use ng-class and some varibale to check if its loaded in teh controller - probably easier

Comment: @userMod2 Edited my answer hope this works

Comment: SASS compile into CSS, for the moment there isn't a way to select a previous sibling in CSS, so you can't do in SASS

Answer (score 0):

If `.spinner` element is placed immediately after to `.slick` element

You can write SCSS

SCSS

```
 slick.slick-initialized {
          display: block;
          + .spinner { display none };
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">       

      <slick init-onload=true data="qNew" dots=true arrows=false>
        <div class=“tile" ng-repeat="question in questionsNew">
          <span ng-bind-html="question.question"></span>
        </div>
      </slick>
    <div class="spinner"></div>

</div>
```

Place .`.spinner` element after `slick` element and use above scss

Comment: Unfortunately didnt work. Ill remember that syntax for the future though. Will go down using `ng-class`